# border setting for the top right left

Tags: css, html

I have the following CSS code:-

```
border:5px solid grey !important;
```

which will apply the style setting to all the border four dimensions upper,lower,right & left. but how i can define the boarder to only applied to the upper,right & left . without having to define separate style for each ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible with this `border:5px solid grey !important;` shorthand methodology.

You need to declare them in the way as mentioned below to achieve what you are looking for.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xk3hE/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div>ABCD</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div{border-width: 5px 5px 0px 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: grey;}
```

**[FURTHER REFERENCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can try,

```
border:5px solid grey;
border-bottom:0px;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define to all dimensions border and then redefine border for bottom:

```
border:5px solid grey !important;
border-bottom:5px solid transparent !important;
```

Also you can set bottom border to `none` or `0` (these means that element will not have bottom border).

P.S. AS you use `!important` in defining border, you need to use it also in redefinision of border.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQrHx/)

Answer (score 2):

```
border-right:5px solid grey !important;
border-top:5px solid grey !important;
border-left:5px solid grey !important;
```

or another shorter way:

```
border:5px solid grey !important;
border-bottom: 0 !important;
```

or you can utilize `box-shadow`:

```
 box-shadow:
 inset 5px 0   0 red, /* LEFT    */
 inset 0 0px 0 blue,   /* BOTTOM  */
 inset 0 5px 0  green,    /* TOP */
 inset -5px 0 0 yellow;   /* RIGHT   */
```

**[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hVBe5/)**

Comment: Second is not OK, the !important will override the bottom: 0 setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the area you want border on that line of code itself like this.

```
border: solid grey!important;
border-width:5px 5px 0 5px!important;
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting you are right, corrected now so take my +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-bottom`:

```
border:5px solid grey;
border-bottom:none;
```